# why does '&' in masterpage link not validate

Tags: php, validation, href

I'm wondering why the following link does not validate in W3schools validator.

```
<a href="../anonymous/anonymous.master.php?page=showproduct.php&id=4">Dvds</a>
```

The issue is the `&` next to the `id`.

The error is described by;

```
did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &amp;.
```

I am using `<!DOCTYPE html >`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it needs to be `<a href="../anonymous/anonymous.master.php?page=showproduct.php&amp;id=4">Dvds</a>` - the & character has special meaning in HTML, so you need to escape it if you're not writing a character code.

Answer (score 2):

you must use `&amp;` instead "&"

Comment: that is so simple...and obvious. Thanks